# MySQL order by date and move null dates at last of the future dates

Tags: mysql, date, sorting, null, sql-order-by

I need to do a sort where `future dates` **first** and `past dates` **last** and if there's a field with a `NULL date`, that should be in between future dates and past dates.

Here is the `query` I used

```
SELECT id, expiry_date, issued_date FROM document
    ORDER BY (expiry_date < CURDATE()),
    (case when expiry_date > CURDATE() then expiry_date end) ASC,
    (case when expiry_date < CURDATE() then expiry_date end) DESC
```

Below is a screenshot of the result

[image]

I need a output where `29th id` should be in between `23rd id` and `22nd id`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

SELECT id, expiry_date, issued_date FROM document where expiry_date > CURDATE() order by expiry_date DESC

union all

SELECT id, expiry_date, issued_date FROM document where expiry_date is null

union all

SELECT id, expiry_date, issued_date FROM document where expiry_date <= CURDATE() order by expiry_date DESC